# getting to web app inside a VM through the internet

Tags: vmware

I have a Virtual Machine running windows server 2003, and in it a webserver.
The network configuration is bridged to the VMWARE host PC and I believe it works fine, I can connect to my VM host from a webbrowser:

```
http://192.168.1.199/myapp
```

That works fine.  But if I try to do it from through the internet, there is no connection. **Why?**

My network is behind a router, I forwarded the ports 80 and 8080 during the test to the VM. I also set off the firewalls.

The same app hosted in another PC (not a VM) can be acessed through the internet without problems

Any help?

Comment: Shut off the firewall in the VM and *on the host*. To test, you'll have to be completely outside your network -- most routers don't handle hairpined port-maps. (accessing your own internet address from the inside, rarely does what you want.)

Comment: Are you `sure` you can connect from the VM to the Internet? Please make sure by loading any Web page from it.